# Transition of wave animation in css from left to right

Tags: html, css

Hi guys I am trying to make a wave animation in css by using an svg here, most of thing works fine but i do have one issue, once the waves reaches the end point, it starts over again all of a sudden and that difference is clearly visible, I want to make the transition smooth for better ui so that to user the wave seems to be endless.

Please check snippet below to understand my problem
Thanks

```css
.wave {
  background: url(https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ratnabh/da8213a27700e0e1c2d1c81961070f6f/raw/3608a5072f4e392b852e5cc3c244841025b32c81/wave1.svg) repeat-x; 
  position: absolute;
  opacity:0.2;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 2000px;
  height: 198px;
  animation: wave 2s cubic-bezier( 0.36, 0.45, 0.63, 0.53) infinite;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

@keyframes wave {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -1000px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wave"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may solve your problem

As you can see in the image, that the height of the Start point and the End point are the same.

So I have increased the width of the `wave` div to the double of the image. and moved div to the very end point of the image which is `1920px` to remove the fluctuation.

```css
body{overflow:hidden;}
.wave {
  background: url(https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ratnabh/da8213a27700e0e1c2d1c81961070f6f/raw/3608a5072f4e392b852e5cc3c244841025b32c81/wave1.svg) repeat-x; 
  position: absolute;
  opacity:0.2;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 3840px;
  height: 198px;
  animation: wave 4s linear infinite;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  
}

@keyframes wave {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -1920px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wave"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This logic will work. But, you have to work on the SVG to match the starting point and ending points.

```css
.wave {
  background: url(https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ratnabh/da8213a27700e0e1c2d1c81961070f6f/raw/3608a5072f4e392b852e5cc3c244841025b32c81/wave1.svg) repeat-x; 
  position: absolute;
  opacity:0.2;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 2000px;
  height: 198px;
  animation: wave 2s cubic-bezier( 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36) infinite;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

@keyframes wave {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 5000% 0; 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wave"></div>
```

Comment: it still flickers a little bit.

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul - It flickers. Because the SVG itself has different endpoints. If you can read my caption carefully. I have already mentioned an improvement point for the same.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out above, the best approach is to adjust the `SVG` file directly to have matching starting and ending points.

```css
@keyframes wave {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -1920px;
  }
}

.wave {
  background: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scottgriv/River-Charts/main/static/assets/wave.svg") repeat-x;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 3840px;
  height: 198px;
  opacity: 1;
  animation: wave 4s linear infinite;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="wave"></div>
```

To adjust the starting and ending points in your `SVG` path, open the SVG file in a code editor to see the `XML`. You can modify the `d` attribute of the `<path>` element.

### Example:

#### Your Original SVG:

```
<path d="M0,0 C135.180854,0 182.771453,50 352.112272,50 C476.394096,50 557.790605,19.606846 751.782984,19.606846 C945.775364,19.606846 984.663736,50 1111.36509,50 C1375.56035,50 1635.95781,0 1920,0 L1920,200 L0,200 L0,0 Z" id="Rectangle" fill="#D8F5EA" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
```

#### Modified SVG (with simplified adjustments):

```
<path d="M0,0 C240,0 240,50 480,50 C720,50 720,0 960,0 C1200,0 1200,50 1440,50 C1680,50 1680,0 1920,0 L1920,200 L0,200 L0,0 Z" id="Rectangle" fill="#D8F5EA" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
```

- The original `SVG` had multiple control points (C commands) to define curves in the path. In the modified `SVG`, I simplified these curves by adjusting the coordinates of the control points while keeping the same number of control points.
- I also changed the `fill-rule` attribute of the `1 element from "nonzero" to "evenodd". This determines how the path fills in case it overlaps itself.
- Feel free to change the fill color too by adjusting the `fill` attribute of the `<path>` element.

#### Full Modified SVG XML:

```
<svg width="1920px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 1920 200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <title>2/1@svg</title>
    <g id="2/1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <path d="M0,0 C240,0 240,50 480,50 C720,50 720,0 960,0 C1200,0 1200,50 1440,50 C1680,50 1680,0 1920,0 L1920,200 L0,200 L0,0 Z" id="Rectangle" fill="#D8F5EA" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```